# GraphQL Unexpected server error when running eas submit

Tags: android, react-native, expo, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm trying to create a submission to the google play store however the bitbucket pipelines have been returning a rather no explicit graphql error when running eas submit.

here is the error I'm getting from the bitbucket pipelines.

```
+ eas submit -p android --type=aab --url=$(expo url:apk) --key=./google-services.json
- Linking to project @jonoirwin/myapp-mobile
✔ Linked to project @jonoirwin/myapp-mobile (​https://expo.dev/accounts/jonoirwin/projects/myapp-mobile​)
Project ID:                     a22b6894-4b43-41c9-b1f8-88ab5d61bbc3
Android package:                za.co.path.myapp
Release track:                  internal
Changes not sent for a review:  false
Release status:                 completed
Archive type:                   AAB
Google Service Key:             ./google-services.json
Download URL:                   https://exp-shell-app-assets.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/android/%40jonoirwin/myapp-mobile-af22e02ecb2540f2878baf07421b79ca-signed.aab
- Scheduling submission
✖ Failed to schedule submission
    CombinedError: [GraphQL] Unexpected server error (Expo error ID: 
    4866d6b013f5c0b2182408467d606063).
```

Answer (score 7):

I also faced this same issue, the cause was I deleted my project from my account on expo and tried to generate another build and there was this in my `app.json`

```json
"extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "random-project-id-of-the-deleted-project-on-my-expo-account"
      }
  }
```

so I deleted the `"projectId": "random-project-id-of-the-deleted-project-on-my-expo-account"` and built it again and it built successfully